# Disable Application Insights dialog on publication

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-application-insights

I have Application Insights enabled in a web project.

As a side effect, I seem to get this pointless dialog on every publication:

[image]

It's complaining about not being able to connect to the respective Azure account. That's fine, it shouldn't do that anyway. It should just shut the hell up.

I do I get rid of this nonsense?

Comment: mouse over it, there should be a close icon in the upper left when the mouse is over it.  once you've explicitly closed it, it shouldn't come back.  if it does, let me know.  What kind of project is this, it seems like it thinks it has application insights but the empty quotes implies it doesnt.

Comment: The close button on the right is what I always use, but it does come back on every publication. The empty string is supposed to be an account name with which it wants to connect to Azure. The project does have App Insights, and that is definitely working.